# Customizing a kivy app logo using Buildozer

Tags: python-2.7, customization, kivy

How do you customize the kivy logo for a kivy app? 
I am using Buildozer in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.  (I realize it wasn't you that added that tag, but rather someone else who edited your question after the fact)

Answer (score 1):

These variables can be set in the buildozer.spec, e.g. `icon.filename` in the `[app]` section.